# Filter Array based on specific date value matching

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter an array and only show items if the date matches the value I assign. I have only ever filtered an array that has objects before, but this one has nested arrays and I'm struggling to figure it out.

```
const branches = [{
    "id": "0741",
    "name": "Manchester Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "12:55",
            "14:10"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "10:40",
            "11:30",
            "11:55",
            "14:35",
            "15:00",
            "15:45",
            "16:05"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0327",
    "name": "London Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "12:45",
            "14:05",
            "14:25",
            "14:45",
            "15:05",
            "16:25"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-10",
          "startTimes": [
            "13:25",
            "13:45",
            "13:50",
            "14:05",
            "14:10",
            "14:25",
            "14:30",
            "14:45",
            "14:50",
            "15:30",
            "15:45"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0221",
    "name": "Newcastle Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "name": "ST",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-10",
          "startTimes": [
            "09:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:35",
            "08:55",
            "09:00",
            "14:55"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
];
```

I am able to do something simple like this which brings back the object that contains this value

```
 const tngCharacters = branches.filter(branch => {
    return branch.name.includes('London Hospital');

  }); 

console.log(tngCharacters);
```

But, I want to bring back all objects based on whether the date is present that I choose. So, ideally the below would bring back the full objects for Newcastle and Manchester Hospital

```
let chosenDate = "2021-09-13";

 const tngCharacters = branches.filter(branch => {
    return branch.appointments.dates.date.includes(chosenDate);

  }); 

console.log(tngCharacters);
```

I think the issue is that appointments and dates are nested arrays and those values would need an index to check each, but I have no idea how to do this.

So, my expected result based on the chosen date would bring back all of the following information

```
branches = [{
    "id": "0741",
    "name": "Manchester Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "dates": [
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "10:40",
            "11:30",
            "11:55",
            "14:35",
            "15:00",
            "15:45",
            "16:05"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0221",
    "name": "Newcastle Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "name": "ST",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:35",
            "08:55",
            "09:00",
            "14:55"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
];
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Do you want to return the whole objects or whole objects that contains `chosenDate` if and only if they are in `dates` array?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue, I think, is that you have to work with the arrays inside apppointments.

```
        let chosenDate = "2021-09-13";

 const tngCharacters = branches.filter(branch => {
     for (let i=0; i < branch.appointments.length; i++){
         for (let j=0; j < branch.appointments[i].dates.length; j++){
             if (branch.appointments[i].dates[j].date === chosenDate) return true;
         }
     }
     return false
    
  });
```

Try that... might work.

EDIT actually with forEach it probably won't work. You might need to use nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 3 levels of nesting, you have to iterate through each of them.
Your dates are an array inside an array, so you have to iterate through it to find nested elements too. I.e. :

```
let chosenDate = "2021-09-13";

const tngCharacters = branches.filter(branch => {
  console.log(branch)
  const inludedSubDates = branch.appointments.filter(a => {
    const thirdLevel = a.dates.filter(e => e.date.includes(chosenDate))
    //   // now you have a subarray that is filtered by the desired search term
    //   // you can do any manipulation, i.e. check if the sub array is empty or any 
    //   //logic you need
    if (thirdLevel.length > 0)
      return true;
  } )
  if (inludedSubDates.length > 0)
    return true;

}) ;

console.log(tngCharacters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try if below works for you. This is using `forEach`, please check the other example using `filter`. Check the optimized method using `some` at the end of the post

```js
const branches = [{
    "id": "0741",
    "name": "Manchester Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "12:55",
            "14:10"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "10:40",
            "11:30",
            "11:55",
            "14:35",
            "15:00",
            "15:45",
            "16:05"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0327",
    "name": "London Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "12:45",
            "14:05",
            "14:25",
            "14:45",
            "15:05",
            "16:25"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-10",
          "startTimes": [
            "13:25",
            "13:45",
            "13:50",
            "14:05",
            "14:10",
            "14:25",
            "14:30",
            "14:45",
            "14:50",
            "15:30",
            "15:45"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0221",
    "name": "Newcastle Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "name": "ST",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-10",
          "startTimes": [
            "09:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:35",
            "08:55",
            "09:00",
            "14:55"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
];

let chosenDate = "2021-09-13";
let chosenBranches = []; // to store the chosen branches
branches.forEach(branch => {
  branch.appointments.forEach(({
    dates
  }) => {
    dates.forEach(eachDate => {
      if (chosenDate === eachDate.date) {
        chosenBranches.push(branch);
      }
    });
  });
});

console.log(chosenBranches);
```

**Using** `filter`

```js
const branches = [{
    "id": "0741",
    "name": "Manchester Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "12:55",
            "14:10"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "10:40",
            "11:30",
            "11:55",
            "14:35",
            "15:00",
            "15:45",
            "16:05"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0327",
    "name": "London Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "12:45",
            "14:05",
            "14:25",
            "14:45",
            "15:05",
            "16:25"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-10",
          "startTimes": [
            "13:25",
            "13:45",
            "13:50",
            "14:05",
            "14:10",
            "14:25",
            "14:30",
            "14:45",
            "14:50",
            "15:30",
            "15:45"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0221",
    "name": "Newcastle Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "name": "ST",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-10",
          "startTimes": [
            "09:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:35",
            "08:55",
            "09:00",
            "14:55"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
];

let chosenDate = "2021-09-13";

const chosenBranches = branches.filter(branch => {
  return Boolean(branch.appointments.filter(({
    dates
  }) => {
    return Boolean(dates.filter(eachDate => {
      return chosenDate === eachDate.date
    }).length);
  }).length);

});

console.log(chosenBranches);
```

A more optimized way using `Array.some`, this is optimized because this will not loop the entire array, `some` will exit iterating the array when the first instance where chosen date is encountered.

```js
const branches = [{
    "id": "0741",
    "name": "Manchester Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "12:55",
            "14:10"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "10:40",
            "11:30",
            "11:55",
            "14:35",
            "15:00",
            "15:45",
            "16:05"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0327",
    "name": "London Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "12:45",
            "14:05",
            "14:25",
            "14:45",
            "15:05",
            "16:25"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-10",
          "startTimes": [
            "13:25",
            "13:45",
            "13:50",
            "14:05",
            "14:10",
            "14:25",
            "14:30",
            "14:45",
            "14:50",
            "15:30",
            "15:45"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "0221",
    "name": "Newcastle Hospital",
    "appointments": [{
      "id": "2000",
      "name": "ST",
      "buildDate": "2021-10-22",
      "dates": [{
          "date": "2021-09-09",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-10",
          "startTimes": [
            "09:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-13",
          "startTimes": [
            "08:35",
            "08:55",
            "09:00",
            "14:55"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
];

let chosenDate = "2021-09-13";

const chosenBranches = branches.filter(branch => {
  return branch.appointments.some(({
    dates
  }) => {
    return dates.some(eachDate => {
      return chosenDate === eachDate.date
    });
  });

});

console.log(chosenBranches);
```